# remotely changing users password with use Net::SSH::Expect;

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $username = '$ARGV[0]';
my $password = '$ARGV[1]';
use Net::SSH::Expect;
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect-> new (
        host => "10.38.228.230",
        password => "lsxid4",
        user => "root",
        raw_pty => 1,
        timeout => 10,
        log_file => "log_file"  
);

my $login_output=$ssh->login();
if ( $login_output =~ /Last/ )
   {
   print "The login for ROOT was successful, Let's see if we can change the password \n";
   $ssh->send("passwd $username");
   $ssh->waitfor ('password:\s*', 10) or die "Where is the first password prompt??";
   $ssh->send("$password");
   $ssh->waitfor ('password:\s*', 10) or die "Where is the Second password promp??";
   $ssh->send("$password");
   $ssh->waitfor('passwd:\s*',5);
   print "The password for $username has been changed successfully \n";
   }
   else
   {
      die "The log in for ROOT was _not_ successful.\n";
   }
```

I am trying to chenge the users password on a remote host by logging to the host as root
but  `$username, $password` doesn't seem to take the values instead if i give hard coded values inside the code it works.

running like this on command line :

```
bash-3.00# ./test6.pl rak xyz12   
The login for ROOT was successful, Let's see if we can change the password
Where is the first password prompt?? at ./test6.pl line 22.
bash-3.00#
```

how can i change the users password remotely

Comment: 1. Don't quote variables needlessly. 2. Don't use single quotes if you want the variable to be interpolated when quoting a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using single quotes here:

```
my $username = '$ARGV[0]';
my $password = '$ARGV[1]';
```

First off, it is quite unnecessary to quote a variable this way. Second, when using single quotes, the content is not interpolated, it is just the literal string `$ARGV[0]`.

This should be:

```
my $username = $ARGV[0];
my $password = $ARGV[1];
```

But a more elegant solution is:

```
my ($username, $password) = @ARGV;
```

Take advantage of the possibility to make the assignment in list context. Or:

```
my $username = shift;
my $password = shift;
```

`shift` will implicitly shift arguments off either `@ARGV` or `@_`, depending on context (whether you are inside a subroutine or not).